# Concat dataframes row wised and merge rows if exsist

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

Df_1:

```
  A  B  C  D   
1 10 nan 20 30
2 20 30 20 10
```

Df_2:

```
  A  B 
1 10 40
2 30 70
```

I want to merge them and have this final dataframe.

```
  A  B  C  D
1 10 40 20 30
2 20 30 20 10
3 30 70 nan nan
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: Could you please describe in details how you want to merge rows? For example what result will be if df_2 = [[10 40] [10 30]]? and if df_2 = [[nan 40] [30 70] [nan 30]] ? What are the rules of merging rows?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the expected result, I think, the index in the second row of *Df_2*
should be **3** (instead of **2**).

Run `Df_1.combine_first(Df_2)`.

The result is:

```
      A     B     C     D
1  10.0  40.0  20.0  30.0
2  20.0  30.0  20.0  10.0
3  30.0  70.0   NaN   NaN
```

i.e. due to possible *NaN* values, the type of columns is coerced to *float*.

But if you want, you can revert this where possible, by applying *to_numeric*:

```
Df_1.combine_first(Df_2).apply(pd.to_numeric, downcast='integer')
```